# JAVA- NETBEANS- Returning a method with code

Tags: java, netbeans

first post here!

So I have this bit of code:

```
    static boolean getInternationalCalls() {
    Scanner intercalls = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Would the customer like International Calls to be included within their minutes?");
    System.out.println("If yes, please enter Y, if no please enter N below.");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Internatinal Calls will be included");
    } else if (scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("N") || scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        System.out.println("International Calls will not be included");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid character, please enter Y or N");

    }
```

Confused myself and dunno how to write it's return statement

Returning it to:

boolean interCalls = getInternationalCalls();

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: [Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is not your homework Jamie. Your method miss lot of stuff and have syntactical error. Please use an IDE like eclipse and would be much easier.

```
static boolean getInternationalCalls() {
        Scanner intercalls = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Would the customer like International Calls to be included within their minutes?");
        System.out.println("If yes, please enter Y, if no please enter N below.");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = null;
        while (true) {
            input = scanner.next();
            if (input != null && (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))) {
                System.out.println("Internatinal Calls will be included");
                return true;
            } else if (input != null && (input.equalsIgnoreCase("N") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))) {
                System.out.println("International Calls will not be included");
                return false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid character, please enter Y or N");

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with:

static boolean getInternationalCalls() {
        boolean internationalCalls = false;
        System.out.println("Would the customer like International Calls to be included within their minutes?");
        System.out.println("If yes, please enter Y, if no please enter N below.");

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y") || scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Internatinal Calls will be included");
    } else if (scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("n") || scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        System.out.println("International Calls will not be included");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid character, please enter Y");

    }
    return internationalCalls;
```

And no, lol

Side project to combine everything I've covered in lectures so far